# lodash orderby with null and real values not ordering correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have an Angular 2 typescript application that is using lodash for various things.

I have an array of objects that I am ordering using a property in the object...

```
_.orderBy(this.myArray, ['propertyName'], ['desc']);
```

This works well however my problem is that sometimes 'propertyName' can have a null value.
These are ordered as the first item in a descending list, the highest real values then follow.

I want to make these null values appear last in the descending ordering.

I understand why the nulls come first.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: "correctly" is a very relative term... putting null values first might be considered correct by some...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The code I needed looks like this...

```
_.orderBy(this.myArray, [( o ) => { return o.myProperty || ''}], ['desc']);
```

Comment: this still sorts nulls abode in asc order, is there a ways have null always at end ?

Comment: @stallingOne i know this is old but for anyone trying to achieve this you can try _.orderBy(this.myArray, o => o || undefined)

Answer (score 46):

The [`_.orderBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#orderBy) function's iteratees can use a method instead of a string. Check the value, and if it's `null` return an empty string.

```js
const myArray = [{ propertyName: 'cats' }, { propertyName: null }, { propertyName: 'dogs' }, { propertyName: 'rats' }, { propertyName: null }];

const result = _.orderBy(myArray, ({ propertyName }) => propertyName || '', ['desc']);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The check can be simple (like the one I've used), which converts all falsy values to an empty string:

```
propertyName || ''
```

If you need a stricter check, you can use the ternary operator, and handle just `null` values:

```
propertyName === null ? '' : propertyName
```

---

Edit: Example with multiple ordering:

```
const result = _.orderBy(myArray, (item) => [get(item, 'propertyName', 0), get(item, 'propertyName2')], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

This will order by `propertyName` then `propertyName2`.

> If `propertyName` is undefined/null then its default order will be set to `0`. (and therefore will be displayed at last because of `desc` ordering on the `propertyName` field). In such case, `propertyName2` will therefore determine the ordering.

Comment: Very close, thank you. I've posted the full solution below.

Comment: Why do you need all the extra stuff `[( o ) => { return o.myProperty || ''}]`? My solution works out of the box. See the snippet. Just replace `propertyName` with the name of the property.

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me the way you had it but it did the way I had it. Maybe its a lodash thing or something. In any case the problem is solved now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Weird. Maybe typescript doesn't like it.

Comment: this still sorts nulls first in 'asc' order, is there a ways have null always at end ?

Comment: @stallingOne - it's not an elegant solution, but you can replace it with some later characters, such as a sequence of tildes - ~~~~~~~~~~~~. A case like this is better handled with the JS sort.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. @BenCameron would you mind accept it?

Comment: @stallingOne this is how I fixed it: return order === 'desc' ? '' : null;

Answer (score 7):

Just for future reference to others you can do this to sort ascending with falsey values at the end.

```
items =>
  orderBy(
    items,
    [
      i => !!i.attributeToCheck,
      i => {
        return i.attributeToCheck ? i.attributeToCheck.toLowerCase() : ''
      }
    ],
    ['desc', 'asc']
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

mine looks like this. PropName and sort are both variables in my solution

```
return _.orderBy( myarray, [
  ( data ) => {
    if ( data[propName] === null ) {
        data[propName] = "";
    }
    return data[propName].toLowerCase();
    }
 ], [sort] );
```

I wanted tolowercase because otherwise the sorting is not correct if different casings

Answer (score 1):

This will put bad values at the bottom, and it differentiates between numbers and strings.

```js
const items = [] // some list

const goodValues = isAscending => ({ value }) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' && isNaN(value)) {
        return isAscending ? Infinity : -Infinity
    }

    return value || ''
}

const sortedItems = orderBy(
    items,
    [goodValues(isAscending), 'value'],
    [isAscending ? 'asc' : 'desc']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
orders = [{id : "1", name : "test"}, {id : "1"}];
sortBy = ["id", "name"];
orderby(
            orders,
            sortBy.map(s => {
                return (r: any) => {
                    return r[s] ? r[s] : "";
                };
            })),
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a function for this (ts code):

```
const orderByFix = (array: any[], orderKeys: string[], orderDirs: ('asc' | 'desc')[]) => {
  const ordered = orderBy(array, orderKeys, orderDirs);
  const withProp = ordered.filter((o) => orderKeys.every(k => o[k]));
  const withoutProp = ordered.filter((o) => !orderKeys.every(k => o[k]));
  return [...withProp, ...withoutProp];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've extended [gwendall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68837660/463663) to also handle case when "order keys" are functions (`_.orderBy` allows that)

```
const orderByFix = (
  array: any[],
  orderKeys: (string | ((o: any) => any))[],
  orderDirs: ('asc' | 'desc')[]
) => {
  const ordered = orderBy(array, orderKeys, orderDirs)
  const withProp = ordered.filter((o) =>
    orderKeys.every((k) => {
      if (typeof k === 'string') {
        return o[k]
      } else if (typeof k === 'function') {
        return k(o)
      } else {
        throw Error(`Order key must be string or function not ${typeof k}`)
      }
    })
  )
  const withoutProp = ordered.filter(
    (o) =>
      !orderKeys.every((k) => {
        if (typeof k === 'string') {
          return o[k]
        } else if (typeof k === 'function') {
          return k(o)
        } else {
          throw Error(`Order key must be string or function not ${typeof k}`)
        }
      })
  )
  return [...withProp, ...withoutProp]
}
```