# Lodash/JS orderBy with nested null values

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

My question is kinda linked to this one, but one step more complex : [lodash orderby with null and real values not ordering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138820/lodash-orderby-with-null-and-real-values-not-ordering-correctly)

Basically I have something like this :

```
let objs = [{x: {y: 1, z: 2}, a: 3}, {x: null, a: 4}];
let sortKeys = ['x.y', 'a']; //this is dynamic, can have multiple fields
```

The user can pass different values for sorting, like `x.y` or just `a` and sometimes `x` is null. So when I use the normal `_.orderBy(objs, sortKeys, ['desc'])` it shows null values first.

How can I do so that the null values appears last?

Answer (score 0):

This solution partitions the array to values that are `null` or `undefined` (`unsortable`) via `_.isNil()`. It then sorts the `sortable` items, and concats the `unsortable` to the end:

```js
const { partition, get, isNil, orderBy } = _;

const fn = (arr, key, order) => {
  const [unsortable, sortable] = partition(arr, o => isNil(get(o, key)));
  
  return orderBy(sortable, key, order)
    .concat(unsortable);
}

const objs = [{x: {y: 1, z: 2}, a: 3}, {x: {y: 4, z: 2}, a: 3}, {x: null, a: 4}];

const result = fn(objs, 'x.y', 'desc');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found the solution myself, kinda similar to yours thanks ! But path can have multiple values

Comment: I've updated to a more generic solution. See updated.

Answer (score 0):

Pure ES6 solution would look like this:

```js
let objs = [{x: {y: 1, z: 2}, a: 3}, {x: null, a: 4}];

objs.sort(({x: x1}, {x: x2}) => {
  const y1 = x1 === null ? Infinity : x1.y;
  const y2 = x2 === null ? Infinity : x2.y;
  
  return y1 - y2;
});

console.log(objs);
```

`null`'s are simply weighted at a maximum possible value and sorted accordingly.

Comment: I need something more dynamic since the search keys are dynamically passed